# Ruby Command Line Implicit Conditional Check

Tags: ruby, shell

I ran the following from a bash shell:

```
echo 'hello world' | ruby -ne 'puts $_ if /hello/'
```

I thought it was a typo at first, but it outputted `hello world` surprisingly.

I meant to type:

```
echo 'hello world' | ruby -ne 'puts $_ if /hello/ === $_'
```

Can anyone give an explanation, or point to documentation, to why we get this implicit comparison to `$_`?

I'd also like to note:

```
echo 'hello world' | ruby -ne 'puts $_ if /test/'
```

Won't output anything.

Comment: if /hello/ is truthy is all that is, it's not false and not nil

Comment: @TonyHopkinson that's not true, you can modify the regex to match nothing -- Will result in no ouput

Comment: Is it like Perl where when `-n` is used `$_` becomes an implicit argument?  Or maybe `$_` is implicit with regexp all the time.

Comment: @Shawn I'm confused now are you asking about truthiness, or are you asking about implicit arguments???

Comment: I'm intrigued now. if /regex/ should always be true. It's as though it's doing a ~= ...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson me too : )

Comment: It behaves the same in `irb` if you put `while gets; puts $_ if /hello/;end` and type stuff at it, although it says `warning: regex literal in condition`.  Weird!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ruby parser has a special case for regular expression *literals* in conditionals. Normally (i.e. without using the `e`, `n` or `p` command line options) this code:

```
if /foo/
  puts "TRUE!"
end
```

produces:

```
$ ruby regex-in-conditional1.rb
regex-in-conditional1.rb:1: warning: regex literal in condition
```

Assigning something that matches the regex to `$_` first, like this:

```
$_ = 'foo'
if /foo/
  puts "TRUE!"
end
```

produces:

```
$ ruby regex-in-conditional2.rb
regex-in-conditional2.rb:2: warning: regex literal in condition
TRUE!
```

This is a (poorly documented) exception to the normal rules for Ruby conditionals, where anything that’s not `false` or `nil` evaluates as truthy.

This only applies to regex literals, the following behaves as you might expect for a conditional:

```
regex = /foo/
if regex
  puts "TRUE!"
end
```

output:

```
$ ruby regex-in-conditional3.rb
TRUE!
```

This is handled in the parser. Searching the MRI code for the text of the warning produces a single [match in `parse.y`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/18bbd05709a4d52704ac217f30c0d9f35830b7f0/parse.y#L9622):

```
case NODE_DREGX:
case NODE_DREGX_ONCE:
 warning_unless_e_option(parser, node, "regex literal in condition");
 return NEW_MATCH2(node, NEW_GVAR(rb_intern("$_")));
```

I don’t know Bison, so I can’t explain exactly what is going on here, but there are some clues you can deduce. The [`warning_unless_e_option`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/18bbd05709a4d52704ac217f30c0d9f35830b7f0/parse.y#L9534) function simply suppresses the warning if the `-e` option has been set, as this feature is discouraged in normal code but can be useful in expressions from the command line (this explains why you don’t see the warning in your code). The next line seems to be constructing a parse subtree which is a regular expression match between the regex and the `$_` global variable, which contains “[[t]he last input line of string by gets or readline](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/globals_rdoc.html)”. These nodes will then be compiled into the usually regular expression method call.

That shows what is happening, I’ll just finish with a quote from the [`Kernel#gets` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) which may explain why this is such an obscure feature

> The style of programming using $_ as an implicit parameter is gradually losing favor in the Ruby community.

Comment: This is the full and correct answer. This little bit of grammar is recursive, so it also applies in `if /hello/ && true`, and in `if /hello/../goodbye/`. I would really like it if it was documented somewhere, though...

Comment: @thanks Matt, your response led me to refine my answer a bit. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

After digging through the Ruby source (MRI), I think I found an explanation.

The code:

```
pp RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile('puts "hello world" if /hello/').to_a
```

produces the following output:

```
  ...     
  [:trace, 1],
  [:putobject, /hello/],
  [:getspecial, 0, 0],
  [:opt_regexpmatch2],
  ...
```

The instructions seem to be calling opt_regexpmatch2 with two arguments, the first argument being the regex `/hello/` and the second being a return value from `getspecial`

getspecial can be found in insns.def

```
/**
  @c variable
  @e Get value of special local variable ($~, $_, ..).
  @j 特殊なローカル変数（$~, $_, ...）の値を得る。
 */
DEFINE_INSN
getspecial
(rb_num_t key, rb_num_t type)
()
(VALUE val)
{
    val = vm_getspecial(th, GET_LEP(), key, type);
}
```

Note that our instructions are most likely telling the VM to bring back the value of `$_`. `$_` is automatically set for us when we run ruby with the correct options, e.g., -n

Now that we have our two arguments, we call `opt_regexpmatch2`

```
/**
  @c optimize
  @e optimized regexp match 2
  @j 最適化された正規表現マッチ 2
 */
DEFINE_INSN
opt_regexpmatch2
(CALL_INFO ci)
(VALUE obj2, VALUE obj1)
(VALUE val)
{
    if (CLASS_OF(obj2) == rb_cString &&
    BASIC_OP_UNREDEFINED_P(BOP_MATCH, STRING_REDEFINED_OP_FLAG)) {
    val = rb_reg_match(obj1, obj2);
    }
    else {
    PUSH(obj2);
    PUSH(obj1);
    CALL_SIMPLE_METHOD(obj2);
    }
}
```

At the end of the day
`if /hello/'` is equivalent to `if $_ =~ /hello/` -- `$_` will be `nil` unless we run `ruby` with the correct options.